# Как организовать массив без повторов

Tags: массивы, сортировка, java

Дан массив А (числовой). Построить массив, содержащий по одному экземпляру элементов массива.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, я в этом деле совсем новичок, что не так.)) На Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{  
        int x[] = {2, 2, 5, 1,  4, 7} ;
        int sum = 0;
        int k=0;
        int z[]= new int [x.length- sum];
        {for(int i=0; i<=x.length; i++)
            if(x[i]==0)
                k=k+1;
            else
            {}
        }
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=x.length; i++)
                {
                for(int j=i+1; j<=x.length; j++)
                if(x[i]==x[j+1])
                    {x[i]=0;
                sum=sum+1;}
                else
                {}
    }
        }
        {if(sum==0)
            {for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++)
                z[i]=x[i];
            }
        else
            {for(int j=0; j<x.length; j++)
        {
        if(x[j]==0)
        {}
        else
        z[j]=x[j];}
        }
        }
        {if(sum==k)
    {for(int i=0; i<z.length; i++)
    System.out.println(z[i]+ " ");
    }
        else
        {for(int i=0; i<z.length; i++)
            System.out.println(z[i]+ " " + 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас очень много "смайликов" в коде (фигурных скобок). И бесполезного кода тоже много. Если коротко, то все не так. В тэгах у вас сортировка стоит, а в коде ее нет...

Comment: Направьте меня на путь истинный, пожалуйста. )) Может, лучше сдвинуть весь массив, если встречается повторяющийся элемент? Но это я не особо представляю, как организовать. (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если бы мне было лень много писать и мало беспокоило, насколько быстро это работает, то я написал бы что-то около этого:

```
Integer[] a = {2, 4, 7, 4, 9, 0};
HashSet<Integer> tmp = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a));
Integer[] b = new Integer[tmp.size()];
b = (Integer[]) tmp.toArray(b);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. ))) Все работает. ))

Comment: Только учтите, такой метод (собственно, так же, как и метод с сортировкой) может менять *порядок* элементов в массиве.

Comment: Вообще-то, использовать  HashSet -- это (IMHO) самое правильное решение.

 Не выдержал, вспомнил Java (и даже проверил на каком-то online сайте). 

    import java.util.*;
    ...
    int a[] = {0, 1, 0, 2}, n = a.length, i, j;
    HashSet<Integer> tmp = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (j = i = 0; i < n; i++) 
       if(tmp.add(a[i]))
          a[j++] = a[i];

Вот и все, теперь в том же массиве `a[]` первые `j` элементов уникальны и расположены в том же порядке, что и исходные.

Comment: Можно ещё проще. В [`LinkedHashSet`][1] порядок перебора элементов совпадает с порядком, в котором эти элементы были добавлены. Плюс, в интерфейсе `Set` объявлен метод `toArray()`, который можно использовать для извлечения элеметов сразу в массив:

    int a[] = {0, 1, 0, 2};
    Set<Integer> tmp = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    for (int v : a) tmp.add(v);

    int res[] = tmp.toArray();

Хотя, конечно, использовать `Set` для удаления дубликатов из небольших массивов - это из пушки по воробьям.

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Answer (score 1):

[[@liliya](/users/24332/liliya)](/users/24332/liliya), если без сортировки и совсем тупо (сдвиг), то обнаружив, что i-й элемент уже встречается, надо все оставшиеся переписать на одну позицию "левее" и уменьшить размер массива на 1.

Естественно, в Java уменьшить настоящий размер (x.length()) не получится. Просто запомните его (в самом начале) в какой-нибудь переменной (`ubound`), которую и будете уменьшать, и делайте циклы до нее.

Небольшая оптимизация -- это не сразу переписывать весь хвост, а корректировать величину шага (она будет увеличиваться на 1 при каждом новом повторяющемся элементе) и переписывать "остаток" на величину шага.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. )